# Jetpack Joyride glitch? Vehicle runs all zero?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I've had multiple runs with each vehicle, but when I check my profile, all my best vehicle runs, excluding SAM, are zero. I've used the regular vehicles, a gold vehicle, the cloud skin, and coin magnet vehicles, but no runs are recorded under best vehicle runs. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Edit: after disabling Google Play Games, updating the app, and linking my Facebook account instead, my vehicle runs are now being properly recorded.

Comment: I tried the Windows Phone version just know and it seems fine.  Which platform are you on?

Comment: I'm on an Android phone (Droid Turbo). Maybe 1.5 years ago I had this game on a different Motorola Android and the runs were recorded, but that was probably a few versions ago.

Comment: You should add your edit as an answer so that people looking for this in the future can find the answer easily.